# Change of variables --- what happened?

Tags: integration

I'm going over a proof which uses change of variables on an integral, which I haven't seen done before, and I can't figure out exactly what happened.
So we have the integral $$\int_\mathbb{R}\left( \int_{-\infty}^{z-x} p(x,y)dy \right) dx$$

So in the innter integral, we set $u = y + x$. I understand that that changes the integral so $y$ becomes $u - x$, but why does $dy$ become $du$ and $z-x$ become $z$?

Comment: With $u=y+x$, you have $u_\text{lower}=-\infty+x=-\infty$ and $u_\text{upper}=(z-x)+x=z$.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the outer integral entirely we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} p(x,y) \,\mathrm{d} y
$$

Now changing $u = x+y$ where $x$ is fixed (this is important, in this integral the only thing that's being summed over is $y$) we get $\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}y$ and for the limits when $y\to -\infty$ we have $u \to -\infty$ (note again $x$ is a fixed finite number!) and when $y=z-x$ we have $u = z-x + x = z$.